# is it possible to dynamically resize the lable in c# without changing the length of text?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am unable to change the size of the lable in windows form application daynamically.

Comment: Please provide us with an error message and a code snippet.

Comment: make sure that the label doesn't have it's AutoSize property set to true. It's set to true by default for a label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set `AutoSize = false` on the label to be able to change the size

[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/3769/tempn.jpg](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/3769/tempn.jpg)